# Where can I find my custom HTTP headers in Azure logs?

Tags: azure, http-headers, azure-web-app-service

I have a REST API running on an Azure server. I turned on Application Logging to "verbose". I can now see all my request coming in, but I can't see the HTTP headers sent by the client. I know they're there, because my code receives them. I tried looking at both the the Application and Web server logs under "Log stream" - not there.

Am I looking at the wrong place? Missing a setting? Is this an authorization issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where can I find my custom HTTP headers in Azure logs?

It seems that this feature is still on the backlog but with no concrete ETA. You may upvote the [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/17207861-custom-request-headers-in-web-server-logs) and keep a watch on for the update.

Comment: Damn shame. This is a basic feature.